# PHP MP3 Info with Symfony Framework

Tags: php, symfony, mp3

Is there a "modern" way to extract mp3 tags using the Symfony Framework and PHP? I have an application that allows for the upload of MP3 files and I'd like to automate the capture of the duration, name, and any other data that we can extract.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages specialized in reading id3 metadata. Search for `id3` on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/search/?q=id3&orderBys%5B0%5D%5Bsort%5D=downloads&orderBys%5B0%5D%5Border%5D=desc) and pick one that fits your needs.